# Exception при создании бина

Tags: java, spring

Пытаюсь изучить спринг, написал вот такой класс и пытаюсь создать bean

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
public class Config {

    @Bean
    public String string(){
        return new String("33");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext ap = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(Config.class);
    }
}
```

Вывод:

```
мар 01, 2017 7:06:04 PM org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext prepareRefresh
    INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@5197848c: startup date [Wed Mar 01 19:06:03 SAMT 2017]; root of context hierarchy
    мар 01, 2017 7:07:03 PM org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext refresh
WARNING: Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAsyncAnnotationProcessor' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/ProxyAsyncConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.AsyncAnnotationBeanPostProcessor]: Factory method 'asyncAdvisor' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: @EnableAsync annotation metadata was not injected
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAsyncAnnotationProcessor' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/ProxyAsyncConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.AsyncAnnotationBeanPostProcessor]: Factory method 'asyncAdvisor' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: @EnableAsync annotation metadata was not injected
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1173)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.registerBeanPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:223)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:702)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:527)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.<init>(AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.java:84)
    at Config.main(Config.java:20)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.AsyncAnnotationBeanPostProcessor]: Factory method 'asyncAdvisor' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: @EnableAsync annotation metadata was not injected
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
    ... 18 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: @EnableAsync annotation metadata was not injected
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:115)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.ProxyAsyncConfiguration.asyncAdvisor(ProxyAsyncConfiguration.java:46)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.ProxyAsyncConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$fa1b2925.CGLIB$asyncAdvisor$0(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.ProxyAsyncConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$fa1b2925$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$cbf85353.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:356)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.ProxyAsyncConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$fa1b2925.asyncAdvisor(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
    ... 19 more
```

Comment: Попробуй написать не `@ComponentScan`, а `@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = Config.class)`

Comment: как собирается проект? как запускается?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скорей всего ваша проблема в том, что у вас класс в пакет по умолчаниюю

Я использовал следующий pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>trash</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-1</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>sample.Config</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

И немного модифицированный ваш класс

```
package sample;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan
public class Config {

    @Bean
    public String string(){
        return new String("33");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext ap = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(Config.class);
        String s = ap.getBean("string", String.class);
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

Все успешно компилируется и запускается.